# Sound issue using pyttsx3 and python in virtual enviroment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyttsx

So basically I am building a python virtual assistant software in a virtual environment  and I want to use pyttsx3 to convert text to speech. The first issue is that if i run pyttsx3.init() I get an error

```
o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    init_speech()
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\index.py", line 31, in init_speech
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\DJETHA\eclipse-workspace\PythonFull\PythonProjects\Betax\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
```

Upon doing my research I found out that using pyttsx3.init("dummy") wont generate any error. The next issue though is that when I run

```
engine =pyttsx3.init("dummy")
engine.say("hey")
engine.runAndWait()
```

I dont hear anything or see any error

I should note that if i used the above code without the dummy in the pyttsx3.init outside the virtual env, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyttsx3
from pyttsx3.drivers import sapi5

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
engine.say('hey')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

i got same error 1 month back.
the mistake i have done is i initially installed python X36 version. that is the cause.
to check the python architecture use below code

```
src\4-4-project>python
>>import platform
>>platform.architecture()
```

if output shows 32bit instead of 64bit then uninstall python X36bit and freshly install python  X64.
don't worry about preinstalled packages though. you simply can save all packages by following code

```
pip freeze > packages.txt
#or
python -m pip freeze> packages.txt
```

you can reinstall all packages after installing python x64bit version by following code

```
python -m pip install -r packages.txt
```

after setting up the python x64bit version and setting the path the following code is enough. don't forgot to install packages again.

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello world")
engine.runAndWait()
```

hope it works.